# C# Runtime Error Declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Tags: c#, runtime-error

Hi I'm have some trouble making this tidbit of code run, as I'm getting a runtime error for  `Kennel.Kennel()` must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial. Please advise and help if you can. Much appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

public class Kennel : IComparable<Kennel>
{
    private string _name;
    private string _breed;

    public string Name
    {

        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public string Breed
    {
        get { return _breed; }
        set { _breed = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Name: {0}, Breed: {1}", Name, Breed);
    }

    public Kennel();

    public Kennel(string name, string breed)
    {
        this._name = name;
        this._breed = breed;
    }

    #region #IComparable<Kennel> Members

    public int CompareTo(Kennel other)
    {
        return other.Name.CompareTo(this.Name);
    }

    #endregion

}


class Run
{
public static void Main()
        {
            List<Kennel> kennels = new List<Kennel>();
            kennels.Add(new Kennel("Alan", "French Bulldog"));
            kennels.Add(new Kennel("Larry", "English Terrier"));
            kennels.Add(new Kennel("Moe", "Gold Retriever"));
            kennels.Add(new Kennel("Curly", "Chihuahua"));

            foreach (Kennel k in kennels)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Breed: {1}", k.Name, k.Breed);
            }


            kennels.Sort();
            foreach (Kennel k in kennels)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Breed: {1}", k.Name, k.Breed);
            }


        }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the first constructor for Kennel() has no code associated with it.   You should add the braces to define the body, even if empty

Comment: That's not a runtime error, that's a compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Kennel();
```

This doesn't make sense.

For an empty parameterless constructor, you still need a body:

```
public Kennel()
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

You default constructor for Kennel has no implementation/body

Replace

```
public Kennel();
```

with

```
 public Kennel() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your error is on this line:

```
public Kennel();
```

You are declaring a method, but there is no implementation.  Either remove it (that's what I'd do), or change it to:

```
public Kennel() {}
```

If your intent is to prevent people from constructing an object without providing the `name` and `breed` values, you can make this constructor private:

```
private Kennel() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what do you not understand exactly? The constructor of `Kennel` must declare a body, what's not clear about that?

If you want the body to be empty, then go ahead and declare it empty:

```
    public Kennel() { }
```

You cannot NOT declare a body.